# Why do some KDE apps appear multiple times in Gnome's file assosiation dialogue?

Tags: gnome, kde

If I right-click a file in Gnome Files and choose "Open with...", it shows applications but some KDE apps (e.g., Krita, Okular, etc) appear multiple times. Why?

[image] [image]